# How to process phplist batchs to send emails simultaneously

Tags: php5, newsletters, phplist

Is it possible to configure phplist to send newsletters simultaneously in 3 or more batches through different smtp servers or how can i achieve this.

Example lets say: I have total of 30,000 subscribers & 1 list & If we create 3 equal batches of 10k subscribers.

- Batch 1 - 1 to 10,000 subscribers - Procssed from smtp1
- Batch 2 - 10,001 to 20,000K Subscribers - Processed from smtp2
- Batch 3 - 20,001 to 30,000 Subscribers - Processed from smtp3

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://resources.phplist.com/system/sending?s%5B%5D=smtp) your can configure multiple SMTP servers:

*To use multiple SMTP servers, you can set the PHPMAILERHOST to be a
semi-colon delimited list of servers. For example*

```
 define('PHPMAILERHOST','smtp1.domain.com;smtp2.domain.com');
```

But that doesn't give you control on which mails go through which server, although in my humble opinion that shouldn't be something for you to worry about in the first place.

Comment: Thanx HBruijn, I just want to reduce the time to deliver the newsletter to the last users of the list & i have a very large database of users which takes more than 12hrs to deliver.

Comment: I think it's possible if we create batches like i have mentioned or we need to setup multiple phplist setups.